# Is there any European organization that issue protest / demonstration warnings similar to what US embassies or OSAC are issuing?

Tags: europe, protests, embassy

I have stumbled across a protest during vacation and I wanted to find out more. My surprise was to find out the some US organizations such as US embassies or Overseas Security Advisory Council (OSAC) are regularly issuing such warnings:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=demonstration+alert&t=brave&ia=web

Example protests warnings by [US Embassy in Bern](https://ch.usembassy.gov/demo10oct2019/) or [demonstration alert in Rome](https://www.osac.gov/Content/Report/6073f611-8f0c-43f8-8da1-171f44eaab77).

Clearly such warnings may be useful for those working in embassies, but also for tourists who are not connected to local news.

I am wondering if any European country has a similar organization that issues such warnings.

**Question:** Is there any European organization that issue protest / demonstration warnings similar to what US embassies or OSAC are issuing?

Comment: This is comparing apples to oranges. Until the EU is further integrated, each European country is doing its own diplomacy, with the exception of a handful of exclusive EU prerogatives such as trade negotiations.

Comment: Just to add: the EU budget is around €160 Billion. The US Federal Budget is more like $4 Trillion. Careful what you wish for...

Comment: E.g.Germany issues [travel warnings](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/ReiseUndSicherheit/reise-und-sicherheitshinweise/reisewarnungen), but that is completely different than short term alerts about demonstrations. Regarding a long term climate of possibly dangerous demonstrations (with the danger perhaps rather coming from the police), we might expect to find Hong Kong or Spain on that list currently - but neither is. -- After all, demonstrations are not dangers per se; though opinions may differ for embassies of a country that has outraged a group of people by abandoned them in a war zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean EU institution, probably no. The EU doesn't issue travel advisories either, that's [left to the member states](https://ec.europa.eu/consularprotection/content/travel-advice_en):

> The foreign ministries of the EU Member States are responsible for providing travel advice to their citizens. In emergencies, this advice may change frequently. The European Commission is not responsible for the accuracy of the travel advice given on the linked national websites.

Comment: I mean any European (not necessary EU and can be at country level). If let's say UK would have a similar service (warn citizens about protests near UK embassies), it would be a good example.

Comment: @Alexei: I've looked at UK and France and they don't seem to give these "demonstration warnings". It could be that some European country does, but i'm skeptical.

Comment: I am also skeptical, but it seems like a nice service that US provides to its citizens.

Comment: I have no idea whether or not UK Embassies issue such warnings, but I do think we get less protested at than the US does.

Comment: The UK does have travel advice like https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/hong-kong covering the current Hong Kong protests

Comment: France also have "travel advice" for each country : https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/ 
It may report "demonstration warning" if it's relevant to travelers.